# Uploading to dropbox using dropnet

Tags: dropbox, dropnet

I started to develop a project to create some dll to comunicate with Dropbox (Desktop).

After searching a while in google I found dropnet and started to use it.

I have two problems with this library on accessing the token and when I'm doing an upload.

Code:

```
Dim client As DropNetClient

        If Not dropboxLoggedIn Then
            client = New DropNetClient("XXXXXXXXXXXX", "YYYYYYYYYY")
            client.UseSandbox = True
            Dim token As UserLogin
            Dim url As String = ""
            Try
                token = client.GetToken()
                url = client.BuildAuthorizeUrl()

                Dim aw As New AuthorizationWindow(url)
                aw.ShowDialog()

                If (Not dropboxLoggedIn) Then
                    client.GetAccessToken()
                    dropboxAsecret = client.UserLogin.Secret
                    dropboxAtoken = client.UserLogin.Token
                Else
                    client.UserLogin.Token = dropboxAtoken
                    client.UserLogin.Secret = dropboxAsecret
                End If
                dropboxLoggedIn = True

                Dim rawData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\users\mysuser\Pictures\anypic.JPG")
                Dim result As MetaData = client.UploadFile("/", "anypic.JPG", rawData)    
            Catch ex As DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                client = New DropNetClient("XXXXXXXXXXXX", "YYYYYYYYYY", dropboxAtoken, dropboxAsecret)
                client.UseSandbox = True
                Dim rawData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\users\mysuser\Pictures\anypic.JPG")
                Dim result As MetaData = client.UploadFile("/", "anypic.JPG", rawData)
            Catch ex As DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try


        End If
```

So, after I do an upload nothing goes to dropbox folder. The result has nothing in properties. Is strange because no error is given.
Also, GetAccessToken not always work.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The error presented when I do getacesstoken in response property is: {"error": "Request token has not been properly authorized by a user."}

Comment: Does `aw.ShowDialog()` wait for the user to login to the Dropbox site? Is the login successful?

Comment: Also can you try to attach fiddler to see what the response from the upload request is?

Comment: aw.showdialog is modal. I'll try to put fiddler and will get in touch after that... Thanks dkarzon

Comment: Everything works fine now. The problem was in the window with the browser.